# JSLint: how not to make THIS function within a loop

Tags: javascript, jslint

In my angular application, I am using a loop to find in an object the nearest value to a given number and return its key.

For example, I want the closest values to 0.5:

```
for (var j in nums) {
      if (0.5 > nums[j]) var prev = nums[j];
      else if (0.5 <= nums[j]) {
        // If the current number is equal to 0.5, or immediately higher, stores that number
        // and stops the for each() loop
        var next = nums[j];
        // Get the value
        var percentage = (Math.abs(0.5 - prev) < Math.abs(next - 0.5)) ? prev : next;
        // Get the key from the value
        $scope.seventyfive = parseInt('0' + Object.keys(nums).filter(function(key) {return nums[key] === percentage;})[0], 10);
        break;
      }
    }
```

JSLint is pointing out that I shouldn't make functions within a loop, so I am trying to avoid that with:

```
filterPct = function (nums, pct) {
      return function () {
        return nums[key] === pct;
      };
    }
```

and

```
for (var j in nums) {
      if (0.5 > nums[j]) var prev = nums[j];
      else if (0.5 <= nums[j]) {
        // If the current number is equal to 0.5, or immediately higher, stores that number
        // and stops the for each() loop
        var next = nums[j];
        // Get the value
        var percentage = (Math.abs(0.5 - prev) < Math.abs(next - 0.5)) ? prev : next;
        // Get the key from the value
        $scope.seventyfive = parseInt('0' + Object.keys(nums).filter(filterPct(nums, percentage))[0], 10);
        break;
      }
    }
```

But this is returning 0 instead of the right value. I am positive I am missing something obvious, but I obviously need another pair of eyes...

**UPDATE**: Thanks to the support I received, this is the error-proof version of the code above:

```
filterPct = function (nums, pct) {
      return function (key) {
        return nums[key] === pct;
      };
    };

    // Store the value with 50% Confidence
    for (i in nums) {
      if (nums.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        if (0.5 > nums[i]) {
          prev = nums[i];
        } else if (0.5 <= nums[i]) {
          // If the current number is equal to 0.5, or immediately higher, stores that number
          // and stops the for each() loop
          next = nums[i];
          // Get the value
          percentage = (Math.abs(0.5 - prev) < Math.abs(next - 0.5)) ? prev : next;
          // Get the key from the value
          $scope.fifty = parseInt('0' + Object.keys(nums).filter(filterPct(nums, percentage))[0], 10);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: "JSLint is pointing out that I shouldn't make functions within a loop" — That's because its easy to create accidental closures. You're using the function *immediately* so that isn't a concern here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filterPct = function (nums, pct) {
    return function () {
        return nums[key] === pct;
    };
}
```

You forgot to define `key` (it should be the first argument of the inner function).